# Tokenizing an Expression

Tags: python

I made a code for tokenizing math expressions:

```
def tokenList(s):
    tokens = []
    # to remove whitespaces in between the expression
    if ' ' in s:
        expression = s.replace(" ", "")
        s_holder = expression
    else:
        s_holder = list(s)

    # identifying each character from the expression, and appending it to the list
    for i in s_holder:
        if i.isdigit():
            tokens.append(i)
        elif i == '*' or i == '/' or i == '^' or i == '(' or i == ')' or i == '+' or i == '-' or i == '=':
            tokens.append(i)
        else:
            return []
    return tokens


print(tokenList(input()))
```

The problem with this code is that if I input an expression with consecutive integers, let's say `123+5`,
it returns `['1', '2', '3','+', '5']` instead of `['123', '+', '5']`. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Tomerikoo how can I do that?

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary code in your function. Your function effectively wants to split the input string at multiple delimiters, and keep the delimiters. So, this one liner will do: `tokens = re.split(r'(\*|\/|\^|\(|\)|\+|\-|\=)', s)`

Comment: @costaparas why not `r'([*/^()+-=])'`

Comment: Rather: `r'([*/^()+\-=])'`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of immediately `append`ing on each digit, accumulate all consecutive digits and append in the end. This can be done in a few ways:

#### building on your approach:

Start by defining a string variable for the numbers. Then, each time you get a digit, append it to that string. Once you reach a symbol, you know that the number has finished - so first append it, reset it and move on to deal with the symbol (appending it as well):

```py
def tokenList(s):
    ...
    num = ""
    for i in s_holder:
        if i.isdigit():
            num += i
        elif i in '*/^()+-=':
            if num:
                tokens.append(num)
                num = ""
            tokens.append(i)
        else:
            return []
    if num:
        tokens.append(num)
    ...
```

#### Using groupby:

Using the built-in [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) you can group all digits together:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def tokenList(s):
    ...
    for key, group in groupby(s_holder, key=lambda i: i.isdigit()):
        if key:
            tokens.append(''.join(group))
        else:
            tokens.extend(group)
    ...
```

#### regex

Lastly, you could use a simple regex to group numbers together:

```py
import re

def tokenList(s):
    return re.findall(r"\d+|[*/^()+-=]", s)
```

Comment: This worked! But can you explain to me what `elif i in '*/^()+-=':
            if num:
                tokens.append(num)
                num = ""
            tokens.append(i)` does?

Answer (score 0):

If the tokens collect only digit and the symbols you specified you can do the following and keep on creating a number string until you find a different kind of character and then append it. Ofcourse, using regex will be a better solution but I have done it in a naive way for easy reading.

```
def tokenlist(s:str):
    s_copy = s.replace(" ", "")
    tokens = []
    output = ''
    for i in range(len(s_copy)):
        letter = s_copy[i]
        if letter == '*' or letter == '/' or letter == '^' or letter == '(' or letter == ')' or letter == '+' or letter == '-' or letter == '=':
            if len(output) > 0:
                tokens.append(output)
                output = ''
            tokens.append(letter)
        elif letter.isdigit():
            output += letter
    if len(output) > 0:
        tokens.append(output)
    return tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def tokenList(s):
    tokens = []
    for i in s:
        if i and i.isdigit():
            if tokens and tokens[-1].isdigit():
                tokens[-1]+=i
            else:
                tokens.append(i)
        elif i in '*/^()+-=':
            tokens.append(i)
    return tokens
print(tokenList(input()))
```